# Partial order: AsyncTask.get() and onPostExecute()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, oncreate

I'm instantiating and executing an AsyncTask from my UI thread (in the
onCreate() handler of my Activity). I guarantee that the Activity
doesn't restart due to config changes (it ignores orientation change,
for example).

In my Activity.onCreate(): I use asynctask.execute(), then the UI
thread does some job, and then asynctask.get(...) is called to synchronize before Activity.onCreate() ends.

According to the log, my asynctask.onPostExecute() gets called *ages*
after asynctask.get() returns. More precisely, onPostExecute is called
after Activity.onResume (!) returns. (So it does get called, my method definition is OK,I use @Override, too.)

I read it somewhere that that since onPostExecute() posts in the
handler of the UI thread, the UI thread must be ready for it -- why
isn't it ready in this case? My application starts with orientation change, but it doesn't cause any config change because of my settings in the manifest.

Is there any guarantee when will onPostExecute() be called *relative
to* asynctask.get()  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the log, my asynctask.onPostExecute() gets called ages after asynctask.get() returns. More precisely, onPostExecute is called after Activity.onResume (!) returns.

`get()` only waits for `doInBackground()` to complete, based on my reading of the source code.

> Is there any guarantee when will onPostExecute() be called relative to asynctask.get() ?

`onPostExecute()` will be called sometime after `get()` returns, based on my reading of the source code. However, this is not a "guarantee", insofar as this behavior is undocumented and therefore subject to change.

Comment: This is really interesting. Indeed, the documentation avoids specifying this, yet this makes onPostExecute() pretty impractical then. The documentation should at least state that there is no guarantee when will onPostExecuted() be called. I assumed, originally, that it gets executed before get() returns. I tried to dig into the source code of Android, but since get() is using very low-level services, I wasn't lucky with finding out the expectable order (if any) of onPostExecute() and get().

Comment: @ThomasCalc: "yet this makes onPostExecute() pretty impractical then" -- not really, as you are the first person in three years that I have encountered that uses `get()`.

Comment: I am using Asynctask in the setup phase of application. It reads data from the external storage. But the application should display its welcome screen only after all data are loaded. Note that it'a not much data, otherwise it would be blocking solution practically (due to get()), but while the data is being loaded, the GUI can prepare its layout (setcontentview etc.), and at the end ofonCreate(), they synchronize.

Comment: @ThomasCalc: I am not saying what you are doing is wrong. I am saying, though, that a claim that "this makes onPostExecute() pretty impractical" is overblown. It might make `onPostExecute()` "pretty impractical" *for your use case*, but yours is not the only use case for `AsyncTask`.

Comment: True. Impractical for the class of my problem.